# Data not inserting in Django Database using Form DTL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here is my model.py file

```
class TestData(models.Model):
    test_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    result = models.IntegerField()
```

And here is my forms.py file

```
class TestDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestData
        fields = ['test_date','test_name','result']
```

And here is my views.py file

```
def photo_single(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = TestDataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = TestDataForm()
        return render(request, 'photo_single.html', {'form':form})
```

and here is my photo_single.html file

```
<form>{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      {{ form.test_date | add_class:'form-control' | attr:'type:date' }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="test_name">Test Name</label>
      {{ form.test_name | add_class:'form-control' }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="result">Result</label>
      {{ form.result | add_class:'form-control' }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="data">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I'm submitting value from form to databasw, I'm getting this in url

http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/?test_date=2020-03-13&test_name=SUGAR&result=23&data=

and data is not saving in database.
Can anyone help me out why ? I'm messed in this. Am I missed something here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def photo_single(request):
if request.POST:
    form = TestDataForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        base_form = form.save(commit=False)
        base_form.save()
        if form.save():
            return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
else:
    form = TestDataForm()
    return render(request, 'photo_single.html', {'form':form})
```

in template:

```
<form method="post" action="/your-url/">
{% csrf_token %}
---------
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)
hope it helps

Comment: Thank you soo much. That was just a stupid mistake. I haven't mentioned the form tag attribute method="POST". It's working fine now. Thanks Alot.